# Prevent Node 'fs' from inserting '\r' in line breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not great with NodeJS but I have managed to put together a basic server script to get the markdown files from a folder and write a JSON file with all the content + frontmatter. The problem is that the resulting JSON has `\r` or `\r\n\r` for some line breaks and not others, which is causing problems in my frontmatter.

For example:

```
{
"section": "Medical\r",
}
```

is different to :

```
{
"section": "Medical",
}
```

resulting in duplicate 'Chapters' being created in my documentation.

I've tried:

- checking for extra whitespace
- manually removing all the `\r` in the JSON which fixes the problem temporarily

I'm using :

- Node v14.15.2
- MacOS 1.2.3
- VSCode 1.55.2
- CRA 4+
- nodemon 2.0.6 to run the server and watch for changes

This is the Node server:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../library/');
let postList = [];

const getPosts = () => {
  fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Failed to list contents of directory: ' + err);
    }
    let fileList = [];
    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      let obj = {};
      let post;
      fs.readFile(`${dirPath}/${file}`, 'utf8', (err, contents) => {
        const getMetadataIndices = (acc, elem, i) => {
          if (/^---/.test(elem)) {
            acc.push(i);
          }
          return acc;
        };
        const parseMetadata = ({ lines, metadataIndices }) => {
          if (metadataIndices.length > 0) {
            let metadata = lines.slice(
              metadataIndices[0] + 1,
              metadataIndices[1]
            );
            metadata.forEach((line) => {
              obj[line.split(': ')[0]] = line.split(': ')[1];
            });
            return obj;
          }
        };

        const parseContent = ({ lines, metadataIndices }) => {
          if (metadataIndices.length > 0) {
            lines = lines.slice(metadataIndices[1] + 1, lines.length);
          }
          return lines.join('\n');
        };
        const lines = contents.split('\n');
        const metadataIndices = lines.reduce(getMetadataIndices, []);
        const metadata = parseMetadata({ lines, metadataIndices });

        const content = parseContent({ lines, metadataIndices });

        // H2 headings
        const h2 = /^## (.*$)/gim;
        const headings = content.matchAll(h2);
        var headingsArrays = [...headings].map((m) => m.slice(1));
        var mergedHeadings = [].concat.apply([], headingsArrays);

        post = {
          name: metadata.title ? metadata.title : 'No title given',
          updated: metadata.updated ? metadata.updated : 'No update given',
          content: content ? content : 'No content given',
          path: metadata.path ? metadata.path : '404',
          section: metadata.section ? metadata.section : 'Misc',
          headings: mergedHeadings ? mergedHeadings : []
        };
        postList.push(post);
        fileList.push(i);
        if (fileList.length === files.length) {
          const sortedList = postList.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1;
          });
          let data = JSON.stringify(sortedList);
          fs.writeFileSync('src/posts.json', data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return;
};

getPosts();
```

I appreciate any tips to stop the  `\r` from being written to the JSON. Thanks.

Comment: Would something like `lines.map(line => line.replace(/\r$/, '')` work? It's replacing the line ending return with an empty string

Comment: Thanks, @evolutionxbox this worked. I was hoping  to prevent the ```\r``` rather than remove them after they were added, but this works fine. Can you make it an answer?

Comment: I would assume that it's not node adding the returns, instead they exist in the file itself?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's the bit I don't understand - I trimmed all whitespace from the frontmatter, copied and pasted the frontmatter also to make sure it was exactly the same, restarted the server, and still one JSON object had the ```\r``` and the other didn't.

Comment: It's likely a line-ending issue. What do you see if you turn on "invisible characters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion from @evolutionxbox above works:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../library/');
let postList = [];

const getPosts = () => {
  fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Failed to list contents of directory: ' + err);
    }
    let fileList = [];
    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      let obj = {};
      let post;
      fs.readFile(`${dirPath}/${file}`, 'utf8', (err, contents) => {
        const getMetadataIndices = (acc, elem, i) => {
          if (/^---/.test(elem)) {
            acc.push(i);
          }
          return acc;
        };
        const parseMetadata = ({ lines, metadataIndices }) => {
          if (metadataIndices.length > 0) {
            let metadata = lines
              .slice(metadataIndices[0] + 1, metadataIndices[1])
              .map((line) => line.replace(/\r$/, ''));
            metadata.forEach((line) => {
              obj[line.split(': ')[0]] = line.split(': ')[1];
            });
            return obj;
          }
        };

        const parseContent = ({ lines, metadataIndices }) => {
          if (metadataIndices.length > 0) {
            lines = lines.slice(metadataIndices[1] + 1, lines.length);
          }
          return lines.join('\n');
        };
        const lines = contents
          .split('\n')
          .map((line) => line.replace(/\r$/, ''));
        const metadataIndices = lines.reduce(getMetadataIndices, []);
        const metadata = parseMetadata({ lines, metadataIndices });

        const content = parseContent({ lines, metadataIndices });

        // H2 headings
        const h2 = /^## (.*$)/gim;
        const headings = content.matchAll(h2);
        var headingsArrays = [...headings].map((m) => m.slice(1));
        var mergedHeadings = [].concat.apply([], headingsArrays);

        post = {
          name: metadata.title ? metadata.title : 'No title given',
          updated: metadata.updated ? metadata.updated : 'No update given',
          content: content ? content : 'No content given',
          path: metadata.path ? metadata.path : '404',
          section: metadata.section ? metadata.section : 'Misc',
          headings: mergedHeadings ? mergedHeadings : []
        };
        postList.push(post);
        fileList.push(i);
        if (fileList.length === files.length) {
          const sortedList = postList.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1;
          });
          let data = JSON.stringify(sortedList);
          fs.writeFileSync('src/posts.json', data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return;
};

getPosts();
```